# Phone Number Validation With Spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have researched all over the place for a phone number validation in JavaScript that adds spacing as they type.

The closest code I came to was

```
$('#ssn').keyup(function() {
    var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var newVal = '';
    while (val.length > 3) {
        newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
        val = val.substr(3);
    }
    newVal += val;
    this.value = newVal;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/nY2QT/.

Expect that is American Mobile Numbers. Anyone know how to do Australia format (XXXX XXX XXX). I tried moving the digits around in the JavaScript but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Try this 

    ^\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$

Comment: Note that the "Australian format" that you mention is only used for mobile and 1800/1300 numbers, not for landline numbers. Note also that reformatting as the user types makes editing an existing value really annoying, because your code results in the cursor moving to the end of the value after every keystroke.

Comment: That's a good point I didn't think of landline numbers. What do you mean by the cursor moving to the end of the value after every keystroke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your code a little bit you can get something like this:

```
$('#ssn').on('input', function() {
  var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  if(val.length > 10) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0,12);
  } else {
    this.value = (val.slice(0,4) + ' ' + val.slice(4,7) + ' ' + val.slice(7,10)).trim();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
 while (val.length > 3) {

          if(newVal.length > 4){
          newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + ' ';
          val = val.substr(3);
          } else {
          newVal += val.substr(0, 4) + ' ';
          val = val.substr(4);
          }

        }
        newVal += val;
        this.value = newVal;
    });
```

Working fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/nY2QT/718/

Comment: Works well but when trying to erase the first four digits after typing a full number a space replaces the the backspace and is only removable by holding down backspace.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes with loop hope it will works

```
$('#ssn').keyup(function() {
        var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        var newVal = '';
        var flag = true;
        while (val.length > 3) {
        if(flag){
        flag=false;
            newVal += val.substr(0, 4) + '-';
          val = val.substr(4);
        } else {
            newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
          val = val.substr(3);
        }
        }
        newVal += val;
          if(this.value.length >= 5){
             this.value = newVal;
          } 
    });
```

Comment: Same as the code above, when trying to erase the first four digits after typing a full number a space replaces the the backspace and is only removable by holding down backspace key.

Comment: @Z-Dog updated the answer added if condition at the end please try now working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have instead three `<input />` elements, give them each `maxlength="4"`, `maxlength="3"`, and `maxlength="3"` respectively. And as soon as the user completes each input, they're moved to the following:

### HTML

```
<form>
  <input maxlength="4" autofocus="autofocus" name="first"/>
  -
  <input maxlength="3" name="second"/>
  -
  <input maxlength="3" name="third"/>
</form>
```

### Javascript/jQuery

```
// Autofocus second after first is complete
$('[name="first"]').keyup(function() {
  if ( $(this).val().length == 4) {
    $('[name="second"]').focus();
  }
});

// Autofocus third after second is complete
$('[name="second"]').keyup(function() {
  if ( $(this).val().length == 3) {
    $('[name="third"]').focus();
  }
});

// Alert numer after third is complete
$('[name="third"]').keyup(function() {
  if ( $(this).val().length == 3) {
    alert("Number: " + $('[name="first"]').val() + "-" + $('[name="second"]').val() + "-" + $('[name="third"]').val() + ".");
  }
});
```

Also, to valide for only numbers, you can use RegEx:

```
// The following code is RegEx, used to validate the inputs so that the user can only type in numbers
$('[name="first"], [name="second"], [name="third"]').on('input', function (event) { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});

// Support for old browsers
$('[name="first"], [name="second"], [name="third"]').on('keyup', function (event) { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

### **[Eureka!](http://jsfiddle.net/nY2QT/722/)**

Edit: answer to Z-Dog's "question":

```
// Autofocus first if backspace is pressed and this is empty
if (!e) e = window.event;
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
if (keyCode == '8' && $(this).val().length == 0){
  $('[name="first"]').focus();
  // And delete last character
  $('[name="first"]').val(
  function(index, value){
      return value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
  });
  return false;
}
```

### **[Eureka 2.0!](http://jsfiddle.net/nY2QT/724/)**

Comment: That would work but one thing I find annoying with this method is if you make a mistake in the last character in one of the boxes and it moves onto the next you can't just back space it :)

Comment: Hm, probably there's a way do to that. Will finish some coding, train and then I'll try to solve it 4 u.

Comment: @Z-Dog There you have it.

Comment: OK there's a problem. If you e.g. type "1234 - 567 - 8", and hit the backspace, not only "8" will be deleted, but also 7 (two numbers at the same time = bad).

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery Mask plug-in

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

It simple to integrate ans use

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it might work

```
document.getElementById('ssn').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/(\d{4}) ?(\d{3}) ?(\d{3})/,
    '$1 $2 $3');
});
```